# How do I get the original number to calculate the sin and cos for a point on a circle?

Tags: c#, math

I got this to move an object in a circle:

```
currentAngle += Time.deltaTime * angularSpeed;
offset = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(currentAngle), 0, Mathf.Cos(currentAngle)) * circleRad;
transform.position = fixedPoint + offset;
```

Is there a way to get the original `currentAngle` (used to calculate a point) from a position on this circle, like backtrack the function?

Comment: Which values do you still have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function is what you are looking for.

In C# it is available as [`Math.Atan2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2?view=net-5.0#System_Math_Atan2_System_Double_System_Double_), which takes `double` arguments. In addition, Unity (which you are probably using given the code sample in your question) has [`Mathf.Atan2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Atan2.html) which takes `float` arguments.